# Why are savings rates the same as CD rates?

Tags: interest-rate, savings-account, certificate-of-deposit

Looking at Ally bank (https://www.ally.com/bank/view-rates/), a 12-month CD has the same APY as a savings account.  (9-month CDs are an even lower APY).

Money in a CD is locked up for 12-months, with a penalty for early withdrawal.  Money in a Savings can be withdrawn any time, but withdrawals are limited to 6 per statement cycle.

What would be the reason for choosing a CD over a Savings Account?  About the only reason I can think of is the interest rate in a CD is locked in, while it is variable (could go down) in a Savings.

What else am I missing?

Comment: CD rates are locked in for the time, savings rates are not.  The bank feels that rates will be lower in the future.

Comment: [Why does a short-term certificate of deposit (CD) have a significantly smaller annual percentage yield (APY) than a saving accounts in some banks?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/119325/why-does-a-short-term-certificate-of-deposit-cd-have-a-significantly-smaller-a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> About the only reason I can think of is the interest rate in a CD is
>   locked in, while it is variable (could go down) in a Savings.

That is the difference in a nutshell. If you think savings rates are going up, then don't get a CD. But if you want to lock them in, then get a CD.

This assumes that both are FDIC insured. It also assumes you don't have a need to touch the money for the length of the CD.